# SSH connect breaks when elasticIP is assigned on AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, amazon-elastic-ip

When I try to connect to an ec2 instance with the route 53 service I bought the SSH connection disappears for no reason that I can determine.

The web server created on it works, but the ssh no longer connects or switches to the public key.  I'm not even sure the DNS or path to the IP is valid.

All the forums state similar problems but the only advice is to scrap the instances and start over.  Of course, that isn't an option if I wanted to develop on the server.

As far as I can tell the SSH or "connect" breaks as soon as I assign an elasticIP, and doesn't reform on the canceling of the elasticIP.

Of course, I bought the Route 53 service with the idea I could start developing and production right away, but as it turns out, I've yet to have a login.  What's Amazon doing to fix the problem?   Is there some esoteric step? as I can hardly conceive no one's ever used a Route53 in conjunction with the ec2.

It all works perfectly until I assign the ElasticIP, I can log in securely, update, program, whatever.  After I assign the AWS EC2 instance an IP the SSH breaks, even before I assign the Route 53.

Comment: I use SSH with AWS instances having an Elastic IP daily without issues or special steps needed. Are you SSHing to the new elastic IP? Assigning one will change your instance's IP address, so connecting to the old one will fail.

Comment: 1) What instance 2) How many IPs does it have, inc public, private, and elastic 3) How many network interfaces does it have?

Comment: Also, please clarify your problem, your environment, and your desired end state. You don't connect to an EC2 instance with R53, you do a DNS lookup with R53 then you SSH to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is amazingly simple, though I've seen questions like this one everywhere unanswered.

When an elasticIP is created, the dynamically created instance address changes.
One simply clicks on the instance to connect again, using the new aws-address.

I think others like me were simply clicking the up arrow in the GIT shell to attempt to reconnect.  The address changes after IP is assigned, when the AWS documentation says to connect to the new address it doesn't mean the elasticIP, it means the new instance address.  Though why a new aws-address change when the instance is the same is a bit of mystery.

Comment: In AWS private IP addresses don't change unless you stop/start - a restart doesn't change them. If you assign an elastic IP address to an instance you lose any automatically assigned public IP. This is well documented, and is shown in the console. If you'd explained your problem more carefully you'd have had an answer within minutes of asking the question.